# issue in conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: javascript, physics

below code to get equivalent Fahrenheit of 12 degree Celsius throws an error saying missing `;`

```
var celsius = 12;
var fahrenheit = celsius x 1.8 + 32;
console.log(fahrenheit);
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication is done with `*` in JavaScript.

```js
var celsius = 12;
var fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;
console.log(fahrenheit)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` isn't a valid operator; though I can see how it could be overlooked.

fixed:

```
var celsius = 12;
var fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32; // x not an operator
console.log(fahrenheit);
```

as a function:

```
const fahrenheitFromCelsius = (deg) => deg * 1/8 + 32;
```